# LINQ returns different sort order for same function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-order-by

On Page_Load I set my GridView with: `myGridView.DataSource = context.Table.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();`. Then I save the SortBy and SortDirection values in the ViewState with: `ViewState["SortBy"] = "Date"` and `ViewState["SortDirection"] = "DESC"`. If I run `SELECT * FROM Table Order By Date DESC` I get the same entries in the same order as the GridView (sounds dumb that I pointed that out, but bear with me).

I also have a button that filters the GridView based on some TextBoxes. Let's say I have `tbName`, `tbType`, `tbFrom`, and `tbTo`. It's code goes like this:

```
protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (GasMarketerDBEntities context = new GasMarketerDBEntities())
        {
             if (context.Table.Count() > 0)
             {
                 DateTime date;
                 List<Table> results = context.Table.ToList();
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text))
                 {
                    results = results.Where(x => x.Name == tbName.Text).ToList();
                 }
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbType.Text))
                 {
                    results = results.Where(x => x.Type == tbType.Text).ToList();
                 }
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbFrom.Text) && DateTime.TryParse(tbFrom.Text, out date))
                 {
                     results = results.Where(x => x.Date >= date).ToList();
                 }
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTo.Text) && DateTime.TryParse(tbTo.Text, out date))
                 {
                     results = results.Where(x => x.Date <= date).ToList();
                 }
                 if (myGridView.EditIndex != -1)
                 {
                     //GridView is in Edit Mode
                     myGridView.EditIndex = -1;
                 }
                 if (ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString() == "ASC")
                 {
                     switch (ViewState["SortBy"].ToString())
                     {
                         case "Date":
                            results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
                            break;
                         case "Name":
                            results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
                            break;
                         case "Type":
                            results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Type).ToList();
                            break;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     switch (ViewState["SortBy"].ToString())
                     {
                         case "Date":
                            results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
                            break;
                         case "Name":
                            results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList();
                            break;
                         case "Type":
                            results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Type).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                gvNominations.DataSource = results;
            }
            else
            {
                gvNominations.DataSource = null;
            }
        }
        gvNominations.DataBind();
        Session["DataSource"] = gvNominations.DataSource;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            while (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
        ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("errorMessage")).InnerText = "[btnRefresh_Click]: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't put any values in the filter boxes and click Refresh it falls past all those if checks and gets to the sorting section which, having been unchanged, should run as Date DESC. **And it does**. The strange part is as soon as the `results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();` line runs (so the same Where clause as when we set results at `List<Table> results = context.Table.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList()`) the order is not the same. The latest entries are at the top, but it appears to sort on a different second field.

**Edit:**

removed the OrderByDescending in the setting of `results` at the start of `btnRefresh_Click`. If I have that it seems to work, but I am wondering why I can't start with the same dataset, then apply the OrderByDescending later in the switch block and come out with the same order as when it's set with OrderByDescending in the Page_Load

Comment: Beyond the sorting of the records based on the order by no sorting is guaranteed. Depending on the sort method used behind the scenes records where the sorted field is the same have no guarantee of order and should not be expected to.

Comment: @EdneyHolder I agree. It seems like when it's ran in Page_Load it sorts by Date, then a, then b, then c, etc. But in the btnRefresh_Click method, if the ViewState variables haven't changed, it seems to sort by Date, then b, then a, then c, etc or something weird. Why does the SQL generated mix up the columns sorted after the one column specified, Date?

Answer (score 1):

One significant point about your example. Avoid using `.ToList()` too early in your query. Build up the `IQueryable` then execute it with `ToList()` once all of your filters and ordering are applied.  This is a big code-smell with EF that leads to performance, and excessive memory use bugs that people wrongly attribute to Entity Framework.

For instance:

```
List<Table> results = context.Table.ToList();
```

This basically loads "SELECT * FROM Table" from the database into memory. Instead, build up your query then execute once at the end. This reduces the data being sent back from the server.

```
using (GasMarketerDBEntities context = new GasMarketerDBEntities())
{
    DateTime date;
    var query = context.Table.AsQueryable;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbName.Text))
        results = results.Where(x => x.Name == tbName.Text);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbType.Text))
        results = results.Where(x => x.Type == tbType.Text);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbFrom.Text) && DateTime.TryParse(tbFrom.Text, out date))
        results = results.Where(x => x.Date >= date);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTo.Text) && DateTime.TryParse(tbTo.Text, out date))
        results = results.Where(x => x.Date <= date);

    if (myGridView.EditIndex != -1)
        myGridView.EditIndex = -1;

    if (ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString() == "ASC")
    {
        switch (ViewState["SortBy"].ToString())
         {
             case "Date":
                 results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Date);
                 break;
             case "Name":
                 results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                 break;
             case "Type":
                 results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Type);
                 break;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         switch (ViewState["SortBy"].ToString())
         {
             case "Date":
                 results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
                 break;
             case "Name":
                 results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
                 break;
             case "Type":
                 results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Type);
                 break;
        }
    }
    var results = query.ToList(); // Single ToList call to materialize.
    gvNominations.DataSource = results;
    gvNominations.DataBind();
    // Session["DataSource"] = gvNominations.DataSource; Don't persist these entities
}
```

Better than returning the entities would be to use `.Select()` to populate a view model with just the columns that you want to display. This reduces the data sent across the wire from DB to web server and from web server to client. This can also allow you to select data from referenced entities without needing to explicitly include those referenced entities nor the overhead/errors that can occur by trying to serialize entities with relations.

```
    var results = query.Select(x => new TableListEntry
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Date = x.Date,
        Type = x.Type,
        // ... etc.
    }).ToList();
```

View models are also safe to persist to session state or what-have you. Don't persist Entities & avoid passing entities to the client. Entities should only exist within the scope of their DbContext. Serializing them to clients leads to issues with circular references tripping up serializers, and also means association/reassociation issues if you try to later use them within the scope of another DbContext.

Comment: thank you, I'm fairly new to EF so best practices like these help greatly! And the only reason I persist the entities is because I have a method to pull from the SessionState then do code on it. But the beginning says if the object in SessionSate["DataSource"] is a List<entity> then do stuff. How would I check that the object in SessionState["DataSource"] is a list<anonymous IQueryable>?

Comment: The issue with putting entities in session state is that you will typically use them later outside of the scope of their DbContext. This means either everything has to be eager loaded first (expensive) or lazy loading will be broken. You can put the loaded view models into Session State. (List<ViewModel>) Anonymous types are best suited for cases where you go to EF to just fetch some data to be consumed on the spot or serialized to something like JSON.